# Bootstrap Datepicker not Auto closing on dom click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

My bootstrap datepicker not closing automatically if i click outside the element.

```
    <div class="formInput input-group">
         <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" id="dateQuoteBid" readonly="readonly" />
         <label for="dateQuoteBid" class="input-group-addon">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
         </label>
    </div>
```

and My Js

```
  $(function ()
    {
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: 'TRUE',
            autoclose: true,
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vh1oknf7/95/

in above Js Fiddle Auto close is working ,but not in my local,
i have updated the Js file directly from gitHub

another issue is look at the arrow button in fiddle it point in opposite direction rather it should point to text box.

Comment: Which version of [tag:bootstrap] are you using? Also, which browser are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: @eric Bootstrap v3.3.5 and browser chrome

Answer (score 0):

I Hope it can be helpful for you .

```
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
     <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"> </i>
    </span>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
      language: 'pt-BR'
    });
  });
</script>
```